# Using Taylor series with remainder

Tags: taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

Arfken and Weber expand $(1+n^{-2})^{-1}$ as
$$(1+n^{-2})^{-1}=1-n^{-2}+n^{-4}-\frac{n^{-6}}{1+n^{-2}}$$
However, if I use Taylor/Maclaurin expansion
$$(1+x)^m=1+mx+ \frac{m(m-1)}{2!} x^2 + \cdots + R_k$$
with $m=-1$, $x=n^{-2}$ and remainder,
$$R_k=\frac {x^k}{k!}(1+x)^{m-k} m(m-1) \cdots (m-k+1)$$ I get
$$(1+n^{-2})^{-1}=1-n^{-2}+n^{-4}-\frac{n^{-6}}{(1+n^{-2})^{4}}$$
Note that the only difference is in the denominator of last term (remainder). So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Just use the division of $1$ by $(1+x)$ and stop whenever you want with the reminder of the division. Don't consider Taylor. Reminder of the division

Comment: You should have power 4 not $-4$ in the denominator.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal that was a typo. Corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici. Got the answer with long division. Because of the form I thought it was Taylor expansion. Anyways got it now.

Comment: You are very welcome. I am glad you made it ! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

What they did is this

$$ (1+x)^{-1} = 1-x+x^2-x^3( 1 - x + x^2 -\dots ) $$

$$ = 1-x+x^2 -\frac{x^3}{1+x}. $$

Now subs $x=1/n^2$.